# How to integrate Recurly gateway in iOS apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, payment-gateway

In my application I need to integrate payment gateway "Recurly" (recurly.com).
is it possible to integrate it in ios apps? if so please give me integration document.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recurly is in beta for its mobile SDK. Please contact support@recurly.com with your github username and your Recurly subdomain to begin.